# JDBC issue when handling code in SQL file

Tags: oracle, jdbc, plsql

I have an XML which is being called as part of software installer code. In the XML, I am executing SQL files using JDBC framework. The installer is failing at a point wherein the JDBC gets hole of the below statement inside a SQL file:-

```
Create or replace procedure test
as 
  Begin
    ...
  End;
/

show errors
/
```

At the occurennce of "Show Errors" , the JDBC fails and installer execution finishes.

I have tried using the below syntax, but still JDBC fails.

```
Begin
   show errors; 
End;
/
```

When I remove "Show errors" from the SQL file, the installer finishes successfully. But I need to have "Show errors" in the SQL file.

Looking for some  assistance here on how to use it without JDBC failing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`show errors` is not a SQL statement, it's a SQL*Plus *command*, so it only works in SQL*Plus and cannot be used through JDBC.

Under the hood `show errors` simply queries the view `ALL_ERRORS` which you can do through JDBC as well:

```
SELECT line, position, text
FROM all_errors 
WHERE owner = user
  AND name = 'TEST' -- replace this with the name of your procedure
```

Comment: Might as well throw in `AND type = 'PROCEDURE'` for completeness; and a [link to the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/statviews_1085.htm).

Comment: Instead of ALL_ERRORS, if in your schema use USER_ERRORS